# How to reset the row index of a p:dataList / p:dataTable on every page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Given below an example of [`<p:dataList>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataList.xhtml).

```
<p:dataList var="row"
            value="#{bean}"
            first="0"
            rows="10"
            rowIndexVar="listRowIndex"
            widgetVar="dataListUIWidget"
            paginator="true"
            paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
            lazy="true">

    <h:outputText value="#{listRowIndex+1}"/>

</p:dataList>
```

This will display a row index for every row starting from 1 (`listRowIndex+1`).

How can I reset `listRowIndex` on every page so that it can start with 1 every time a page is changed (i.e it should start with 1 on every page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value of `first` in a view bean and change the text output to

```
<h:outputText value="#{listRowIndex - bean.first + 1}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear the Beans data by creating new instance so the Data will be reset 
or you can change the scope of the managedBean